# Understanding ECMAScript's ReturnIfAbrupt(AbstractOperation())

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

I know there are a few posts about this, but I have yet to find a good explanation of what a `ReturnIfAbrupt(AbstractOperation())` statement evaluates to when the `AbstractOperation()` is not an [abrupt completion](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-completion-record-specification-type)?

> According to [ECMAScript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-returnifabrupt) **ReturnIfAbrupt(AbstractOperation())** means:
>
> 1. Let hygienicTemp be AbstractOperation().
> 2. If hygienicTemp is an abrupt completion, return hygienicTemp.
> 3. Else if hygienicTemp is a Completion Record, set hygienicTemp to hygienicTemp.[[Value]].
>
> Where hygienicTemp is ephemeral and visible only in the steps pertaining to ReturnIfAbrupt.

Taking the last line in the [[[Construct]]](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) operation as an example:

1. That line is `Return ? envRec.GetThisBinding()`
2. Which is [equivalent to](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands): `Return ReturnIfAbrupt(envRec.GetThisBinding())`
3. Assuming `GetThisBinding()` does not throw an `Error` (i.e. no *abrupt completion*), I have no idea what is actually returned
4. The quoted `ReturnIfAbrupt` definition above specifically says `hygenicTemp` only relates to the steps within the definition itself. It gives no hint of what the expression as a whole evaluates to

Comment: If I understand correctly, it means that a Completion Record is "unwraped" and its `[[Value]]` is returned.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling . That was my suspicion as well, but I could not find any evidence supporting that conclusion within the spec's definition of `ReturnIfAbrupt`. It basically says `hygenicTemp` is ephemeral, and not accessible outside the definition. Thus, I felt it was just speculation.

Comment: It used to be as "simple" as this: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-returnifabrupt . So it would have been equivalent to: `arg = <some operation>; if (IsAbrupt(arg)) { return arg; } else { arg = arg.[[Value]]};` if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit you've quoted is for when the value *isn't* used. But your `[[Construct]]` example *is* using the value.

For that, you needed to scroll down a little bit:

> Algorithms steps that say or are otherwise equivalent to:
>
> 1. Let result be AbstractOperation(ReturnIfAbrupt(argument)).
>
> mean the same thing as:
>
> 1. If argument is an abrupt completion, return argument.
> 2. If argument is a Completion Record, set argument to argument.[[Value]].
> 3. Let result be AbstractOperation(argument).

So for `Return ? envRec.GetThisBinding()`, when `envRec.GetThisBinding()` doesn't return an abrupt completion, that line in `[[Construct]]` returns the `[[Value]]` of the non-abrupt completion record from `envRec.GetThisBinding()` (the `this` value).

Comment: I'm not sure the part you quoted applies here. That line in `[[Construct]]` doesn't pass the "result" of `ReturnIfAbrupt(argument)` to an other operation. But maybe `Return` is considered an operation here, so it is "equivalent"?

Comment: @FelixKling - Yes, `Return` is using the value, which is why this part applies rather than the part quoted in the question. "Return ? envRec.GetThisBinding()" is just a shorter way to write "Let X be ? envRec.GetThisBinding()" and then "Return X".

Comment: Facepalm, I somehow missed that part. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks TJ. @FelixKling , it says `Algorithms steps that say or are otherwise equivalent to:...`, and `Return ReturnIfAbrupt(op)` returns whatever `ReturnIfAbrupt(op)` evaluates to (given no `abrupt completion`). So to my understanding, the last line is caught by this definition.